# Как сохранить файл в папку Фотки?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

```
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSPicturesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSData * binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.Image);
[binaryImageData writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile3.png"] atomically:YES];
```

Файл там не появляется. До этого использовал директорию NSDocumentDirectory - файл сохранялся.
В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил так:     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.Image, self, nil, nil);